# SQL Server 2008 - merge rows when condition matched

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a stored procedure and getting the following value.

```
Name    ID   NewID  Qty     Rqty    Total
Test1   1            5       4        9
Test2   10   1001    3       0        3
Test2   1001         4       2        6
Test3   15   1005    0       0        0
Test3   1005         3       4        7
```

If you look the `Test3`, where first id `15` has a new id `1005` But the `Qty` and `Rqty` is `0`, next line I am getting ID `1005` and `Qty, Rqty` `3` and `4`, total `7`and this is correct.

What I am trying to do is when any ID got a new ID and `Qty, Rqty` both are `0`, I need the following output in on row

```
Test3   15  1005    3   4   7
```

So, my final results will be -

```
Name    ID   NewID   Qty    Rqty  Total
Test1   1             5      4      9
Test2   10   1001     3      0      3
Test2   1001          4      2      6
Test3   15   1005     3      4      7
```

My stored procedure is  -

```
select Name, ID, NewID, Qty, RQty, SUM(Qty + RQty) as Total  
from table1
Group By Name, ID, NewID, Qty, RQty
Order by Name
```

Could anyone help to solve this issue please.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the stored procedure?

Comment: You need to change the SP or you have the data already stored and need to change in after the SP is executed?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino, please see the updated question

Comment: @gotqn, I am not sure how can I do this, any idea will be helpful

Comment: Does any given `Name` ever have more than 2 rows?   Could there more than one `NewID` with all zeros for the same `Name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to generate a psuedo "grouping" ID and NewID based on your conditions, group on those fields and select the MIN and MAX of the original ID and NewID along with aggregates of your other values. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tests
(
    Name    varchar(10),    
    ID      int,
    [NewID] int NULL,
    Qty     int,
    Rqty    int
);
INSERT dbo.Tests (Name,ID,[NewID],Qty,Rqty)
--VALUES ('Test1',1,NULL,5,4)
--    ,('Test2',10,1001,3,0)
--    ,('Test2',1001,NULL,4,2)
--    ,('Test3',15,1005,0,0)
--    ,('Test3',1005,NULL,3,4);
VALUES ('test1',1,101,0,0)
      ,('test1',101,NULL,2,4)
      ,('test2',2,102,0,0) 
      ,('test2',102,NULL,4,5) 
      ,('test3',3,103,0,0) 
      ,('test3',103,NULL,3,3) 
      ,('test4',4,104,0,0) 
      ,('test4',104,NULL,1,3) 
      ,('test5',5,105,0,0) 
      ,('test5',105,NULL,3,6);

SELECT t.Name,
       min(t.ID) AS ID,
       max(t.[NewID]) AS [NewID],
       sum(t.Qty) AS Qty,
       sum(t.Rqty) AS Rqty,
       sum(t.Qty)+sum(t.Rqty) AS Total
FROM dbo.Tests AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN Qty = 0 AND Rqty = 0 AND t.[NewID] IS NOT NULL THEN [NewID] ELSE ID END,
                    CASE WHEN Qty = 0 AND Rqty = 0 AND t.[NewID] IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE coalesce([NewID],-1) END)
            ) x(GroupingID, GroupingNewID)
GROUP BY Name,x.GroupingID,x.GroupingNewID
ORDER BY Name,max(t.ID);
```

[image: Results of above query]

Comment: First view value is working, but after that it is not working, it is not adding the value, returning 0, 0

Comment: Can you give some more data, including those that are working and those that are not.

Comment: Only first 4 rows where condition is matching, giving correct value after that its not including, giving 0

Comment: {test1 1 101 0 0 0
test1 101  2 4 6
test2 2 102 0 0 0
test2 102  4 5 9
test3 3 103 0 0 0
test3 103  3 3 6
test4 4 104 0 0 0
test4 104  1 3 4
test5 5 105 0 0 0
test5 105  3 6 9}

Comment: test5 returing is - test5  5 105 0 0 0

Comment: Nick, it might be any 1 value is 0 for newid mean when like qty has value and rqty has 0, that time its causing problem

Comment: I am not seeing the behaviour you're describing; with that last set of test data test5 is grouping as expected. I've edited my answer to show the table creation, you can take this and run it directly in SSMS and see the results shown.

Comment: when I am getting any value like this, how can I do {test6 6 106 0 0 0, test6 106  3 0 3}

Comment: but they are different test numbers

Comment: Hi Nick, I have updated the value, when RQty value is 0 it's returning wrong value